# Connect MongoDB from C# .Net

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I am trying to connect to my client server in another system, but nothing happens when I run the code. I debugged the code and found the compiler is not passing after the line "using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))".

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CallMain().Wait();
        }

static async Task CallMain()
        {
                var conString = "mongodb://215.658.326.54:2154";
                var Client = new MongoClient(conString);
                var DB = Client.GetDatabase("db_name");
                var collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("User");
                var filter = new BsonDocument();
            try
            {
                 using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
                {
                    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                    {
                        foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(doc);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
}
```

please provide me a solution for this or guide me a working code to connect to mongodb in another server and fetech data.

Comment: Try to debug your source code!

Comment: "Nothing happens" is as bad as "it didn't work". Step through your code. Do you successfully connect? What path does the code take?

Comment: Agreed with @duDE.
If nothing happens maybe you're in a infinite loop or similar. Try to debug your code line-by-line and understand where it fails.

Comment: it fails in the line, 


using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))

after this there is no response.

Comment: Nothing happen is because `CallMain()` is a async method, you can't catch exception in your thread like this.

Comment: can you please provide me a good way to connect to my mongo client and fetch data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an async method you are trying to execute, so try using Task.Run to execute the method

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => CallMain().Wait());
}
```

And you could use this method to retrieve your data instead of iterating a cursor

```
var results = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

foreach(var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("whatever");
}
```

Also, your filter variable is an empty document, so i assume you want to retrieve all records, if so you can use this

```
var results = await collection.Find(x => true).ToListAsync();
```

Find() accepts lambda and also filter created from Builders. Look into Builders, for example

```
var filter = Builders<YourModel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.SomeField, "SomeValue");
var results = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

And the equivelant with lambda would be

```
var results = await collection.Find(x => x.SomeField == "SomeValue").ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code (mongodb c# driver 2.0.1)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = MainAsync(args);
    t.Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
    var db = client.GetDatabase("name");
    var coll = db.GetCollection<Book>("collName");}
```